# Customize requestFinished, requestFailed conditions for ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest, nsurlrequest

I would like to customize `ASIHTTPRequest` to be more picky about when it fires `requestFinished`. In particular, I *only* want `requestFinished` to be called when the status code is `200`. Other than that, for all other status codes, or network-level failures, I want a `requestFailed`. Is there a way to override the default functionality cleanly, or am I opening a can of worms by trying to modify `ASIHTTPRequest`? If there is a way to do it cleanly, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add a piece of code here in `ASIHTTPRequest.m`

```
- (void)reportFinished
{
    if (self.responseStatusCode !=200){
    //this way, you can get error message you want in requestDidFailed:.
    return [self failWithError:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"Failed" code:ASIConnectionFailureErrorType userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Failed to get connection",NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,nil]]];
    }

     ... 
     ... 
}
```

Comment: In this case you have receive entire response body even if you don't need it.

Comment: maybe you are right. but since you don't need it, there no harm doing it. And, you can override `responseString` in that method if fail happen.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass ASIHTTPRequest and provide your own reportFinished method that does what the existing one does except it should first check the responseStatusCode, calling the failure delegate if it's not 200.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `request:didReceiveResponseHeaders:` method of ASIHTTPRequestDelegate, headers dictionary should contain response code.

If the value is not appropriate just call `[request failWithError:error]`. *error* can be `ASIRequestCancelledError` for example.

In this case you don't need to receive all response body.